# Symfony2 Swiftmailer sends emails when the project is in my PC's virtual server but doesn't when I upload it to shared hosting

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

When my Symfony project is in my PC's wamp it sends emails just fine but after I upload it to shared hosting it doesn't but after some time it still redirects and I get "Success" flashbag. The only different is that in the server when sending it page is loading much longer (other pages loads pretty fast).

some people suggested for someone to remove `spool:     { type: memory }` line from config.yml
 but if I do so I get error: The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony2 doesn't work well on most shared hosting solutions, you should get in touch with the system admin as it is most probably due to the server's configuration, if Swiftmailer is even installed.